# SMS using asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

can you please show me how to send an SMS to a mobile phone through ASP.Net web Application.

I will very much appreciate it if you can help me with that.

Thank you in Advance.

Austin

Answer (score 2):

By using an [SMS Gateway](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSMS_gateway&ei=fM58TOyBDM2COIjT1IIE&usg=AFQjCNFHeJLOD2IkBcXo7lCKHqfaDneUJw). Prices could vary between the [different providers](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=active&q=sms+gateway&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=81dbead5084ccb77) and the number of messages you would like to send.